# joint between ground body & dynamic bodies ( Rope )

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

i am implementing a rope which is hanging from top of the screen , now i have use one dynamic body for creating ropes & i use Revolute joints for joining this all dynamic bodies to create a rope. i successfully created rope , Now when i tried to join my this rope on ground body then it's not getting fixed on it . i guess it's happening because of the dynamic body i used in my rope creation. i am trying to join this with Distance joint , but it's not working, i really stuck with this from couple of weeks .. please help .

ropes:

```
b2Body* link;
CGSize s = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;

CGFloat linkHeight = 0.24;
CGFloat linkWidth = 0.1;

link = world->CreateBody( &bodyDef );
link->CreateFixture( &fixtureDef );


PhysicsSprite* segmentSprite = [PhysicsSprite spriteWithFile:@"rope_seg_new2.png"];
[self addChild:segmentSprite];
[segmentSprite setPhysicsBody:link];


//set up the common properties of the joint before entering the loop



revoluteJointDef.localAnchorA.Set( 0,  linkHeight);
revoluteJointDef.localAnchorB.Set( 0, -linkHeight);


//use same definitions to create multiple bodies

for (int i = 0; i < 10 ; i++) {



    newLink = world->CreateBody( &bodyDef );
    newLink->CreateFixture( &fixtureDef );
    PhysicsSprite* segmentSprite = [PhysicsSprite spriteWithFile:@"rope_seg_new2.png"];
    [self addChild:segmentSprite];
    [segmentSprite setPhysicsBody:link];

    revoluteJointDef.bodyA = link;
    revoluteJointDef.bodyB = newLink;

    world->CreateJoint( &revoluteJointDef );

    link = newLink;  //prepare for next iteration
}
```

joint between GroundBody &  Rope:

```
 Distance joint :

b2DistanceJointDef jointDef;

jointDef.Initialize(referencebody, link, referencebody->GetWorldCenter(), link-

>GetWorldCenter());

world->CreateJoint( &jointDef );
```

here, referencebody : groundbody .. link : rope body

Comment: Distance joint i provided is not working ....

Comment: i want to make sure that you have added joint to world and not just initialising it.

Comment: @BaSha yaa exactly .. i have added to world like this world->CreateJoint( &jointDef );

Comment: @BaSha , i really stuck with this problem dude, even i tried all possible joints in this .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got answer through Revolute joint ...

```
b2RevoluteJointDef revoluteJointDef;
revoluteJointDef.bodyA = referenceBody;
revoluteJointDef.bodyB = lastLink;
revoluteJointDef.localAnchorA = startPos;//world coords, because m_groundBody is at (0,0)
revoluteJointDef.localAnchorB.Set(0,0);//center of circle
world->CreateJoint( &revoluteJointDef );
```

Comment: I am also looking for same thing,this will help me a lot.

Comment: @Rao27 ok buddy .. i will surely help you on this.